# react-native release apk giving error in alert box {"line":132,"column":7285,"sourceURL":"index.android.bundle"}

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and creating apk using command sudo **react-native run-android --variant=release** app is working fine on usb debbuging, but when i am creating apk and run it on mobile device it gives error alert box

```
 {"line":132,"column":7285,"sourceURL":"index.android.bundle"}
```

I am sharing package.json and babel.config.json

```
{
"name": "ReactNativeApp",
"version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
"scripts": {
  "android": "react-native run-android",
  "ios": "react-native run-ios",
  "start": "react-native start",
  "test": "jest",
  "lint": "eslint ."
 },
"dependencies": {
 "@bam.tech/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.2.3",
 "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.2.2",
 "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
 "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.1.0",
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.2",
 "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.2",
 "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.2.0",
 "core-js": "^3.6.4",
 "react": "16.9.0",
 "react-native": "0.61.5",
 "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^3.0.0",
 "react-native-bootsplash": "^0.1.0",
 "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.6.0",
 "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
 "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.3",
 "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
 "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
 "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
 "react-native-interactive-image-gallery": "^0.1.2",
 "react-native-masonry-list": "^2.16.1",
 "react-native-material-dialog": "^0.7.7",
 "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
 "react-native-modal": "^11.5.4",
 "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.5.1",
 "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.7.0",
 "react-native-modals": "^0.19.9",
 "react-native-photo-upload": "^1.3.0",
 "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
 "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.2",
 "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
 "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
 "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^4.1.0",
 "react-native-tab-view": "^2.13.0",
 "react-native-textarea": "^1.0.3",
 "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
 "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
 "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.4"
},
 "devDependencies": {
 "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
 "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
 "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
 "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
 "eslint": "^6.8.0",
 "jest": "^25.1.0",
 "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
 "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
 },
 "jest": {
 "preset": "react-native"
 }
}
```

and babel.config.json

```
 module.exports = {
 presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
 };
```

Comment: Need more info, try delete index.android.bundle that is generated

Comment: I have updated my question with more information like package.json and babel.config.json,@/anthony-willis-Munoz I tried your solution but not work for me

Comment: does anyone know how to solve this error ??

Comment: its really weird error, you follow the react native guide before trying? https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android. If you have followed the only thing you have left, is to copy your project and test isolate components and figure out what is the component that give you the problem for example auth screens then home screens...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using APIs call in the android and uses HTTP calls which is not secure then this problem will occur in Android API >= 28.

This problem comes in API < 28 but android handles it but now after API 28 they are not handling it rather want developers to use HTTPS api calls for added security. As android versions are coming they are more towards security.

But if you still want to use HTTP API calls in your android app, be it in react native or any other you have to add this in `androidmanifest.xml` file

```
 <application
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            .......>
 </application>
```

The value of `usesCleartextTraffic` is by default set to false in API > 28.So we have to manually set it to true to make it working.